# Can't load Python module by its path - __import__ says ImportError: Import by filename is not supported

Tags: python-2.7

*I'm far from Python expert, so please bear with me.* 
I'm using [Slack python bot library](http://github.com/slackhq/python-rtmbot/), which utilizes module loading to execute users code. 
I noticed a weird thing - when I launch my script, it says `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported` on a line `self.module = __import__(name)` (where name is relative path to the Python file).
 I don't quite understand the problem, because the owners of the library test their code with both 2.x and 3.x Python, and it DOES work on TravisCI.
I'm using Python 2.7.8 on Windows 7.
How do I fix the problem? I suspect something on my system is wrong. I read similar questions on SO and worked around the issue by using `imp.load_source`, but I would like to get to the bottom of it.
P.S. It also works if I upload it to Heroku, which by default runs 2.7.12